# Java If else statement

Tags: java

Hi I have 3 variables u v w and it will either equal zero or perform a simple division depending on the statement and i want to take those 3 values and apply it towards another if statement down below to do a compare equals but I am assuming that it can't read whatever u v w is from the above statements. How can i make this work? Thanks

```
  if(t3 != 0){
      double u = t/t3;
  }
  else if(t4 != 0){
      double v = t1/t4;
  }
  else if(t5 != 0){
      double w = t2/t5;
  }
  else if(t3 == 0){
      double u = 0;
  }
  else if(t4 == 0){
      double v = 0;
  }
  else if(t5 == 0){
      double  w = 0;
  }



   if((u == v) && (v == w))  
   {
            blah blah


        }
       else 
             blah blah
```

Comment: why you are declaring variable again and again??

Comment: Don't compare doubles like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you should use `else if`'s?

```
double u = 0.0d, v = 0.0d, w = 0.0d;
if(t3 != 0){
    u = t/t3;
}
if(t4 != 0){
    v = t1/t4;
}
if(t5 != 0){
    w = t2/t5;
}
//.. do other stuff...
```

The reason why the original program didn't work is because java has no algebraic engine. The compiler doesn't know that `if(tmp == 0)` and `if(tmp != 0)` are opposite conditions. Furthermore you use an `else if`. The result is that the compiler thinks there is a third option where `u` (and other variables) never get initialized. Furthermore most java compiler will enforce you to define variables out of if-scopes anyway in order to use them outside.

Comment: double u,v,w are already declared outside. Why would you want to declare it again inside the if?

Comment: @Nisha: as always, copy-paste is a bad habbit... :P

Answer (score 5):

Define those variable out of the `if` conditions. In your case, your variable are having scope inside the `if` condition's curly braces

```
double u = 0;
double v = 0;
double w = 0

if(t3 != 0){
       u = t/t3;
  } else if(t4 != 0){
       v = t1/t4;
  } else if(t5 != 0){
       w = t2/t5;
  }
  //else if(t3 == 0){ // Seems, these conditions are redundant, since those variables are already zero
  //     u = 0;
  //}
  //else if(t4 == 0){
  //    double v = 0;
  //}
  //else if(t5 == 0){
  //      w = 0;
  //}
```

Comment: I think the last statements are not necessary since `u`, `v` and `w` are already zero.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran, suppose if `t3!=0` then it will not check condition for `t4` and `t5`.

Comment: @Himanshu, couldn't check the logic no time, I just sorted out the compilation error problem only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variables outside the `if { }` blocks. Conditional declarations is not confirmation that variable will be declared all time.

If you will initialize `u`, `v` and `w` with 0 then last three conditions in your code will be eliminated.

```
double u = 0.0d, v = 0.0d, w = 0.0d;

if(t3 != 0){
    u = t/t3;
} 
else if(t4 != 0){
    v = t1/t4;
}
else if(t5 != 0){
    w = t2/t5;
}
```